# Hide div if href contains keyword

Tags: jquery, html

I need to hide with jQuery a div container `hide_this_div` if a `href` contains a the keyword "gutschein". Here is a example:

```html
<div class="event_title">
  <strong><a href="index.php/kurse/kursdetails/some-gutschein" title="">Some Gutschein</a></strong>
</div>

 
<div class="item hide_this_div block">
something here
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use `a[href*="gutschein"]` selector to find elements with a having a specific word in href.

Here this `*` is a wildcard which essentially is checking if href contains the specific word anywhere.

```
$(function(){
   if($('a[href*="gutschein"]').length > 0){
      $(".hide_this_div").hide();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `search` function in the `href` attribute on document ready to filter the anchor try below code

```
$(function(){
   if($('.myDiv a').attr('href').search(keyword) != -1){
      $('.myDiv').hide();
   }
})
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with more explanations. Avoid code only answer, take a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet of code.

```
var anchorVal= $('a').attr('href');
if (anchorVal.includes("gutschein")) {
     $(".item .hide_this_div").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find anchor text and using `indexOf` you get what you want.

```js
var txt = $('.event_title').find('a').html();
if (txt.indexOf('Gutschein') != -1) {
  $('.hide_this_div').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_title">
  <strong><a href="index.php/kurse/kursdetails/some-gutschein" title="">Some Gutschein</a></strong>
</div>


<div class="item hide_this_div block">
  something here
</div>
```